# Sqlite3 Update Inserts a single row's values for target table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sql-update

I am attempting to run an update on a 10 row table (olddb.People) from another 10 row table (newdb.Peeps).

```
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'D:/tutorial2.db' AS olddb;
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE ':memory:' as newdb;
sqlite> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newdb.Peeps(unix INT, datestamp INT, value INT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO newdb.Peeps SELECT * FROM olddb.People;
sqlite> UPDATE newdb.Peeps SET datestamp = 20, value = 45 WHERE unix = 10;
sqlite> UPDATE newdb.Peeps SET datestamp = 20, value = 45 WHERE unix = 14;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM olddb.People;
10|150|5
11|165|5.5
12|180|6
13|195|6.5
14|210|7
15|225|7.5
16|240|8
17|255|8.5
18|270|9
19|285|9.5
sqlite> SELECT * FROM newdb.Peeps;
10|20|45
11|165|5.5
12|180|6
13|195|6.5
14|20|45
15|225|7.5
16|240|8
17|255|8.5
18|270|9
19|285|9.5
sqlite> UPDATE olddb.People SET datestamp = (SELECT datestamp FROM newdb.Peeps WHERE unix = newdb.Peeps.unix), value = (SELECT value from newdb.Peeps WHERE unix = newdb.Peeps.unix);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM olddb.People;
10|20|45
11|20|45
12|20|45
13|20|45
14|20|45
15|20|45
16|20|45
17|20|45
18|20|45
19|20|45
sqlite> SELECT * FROM newdb.Peeps;
10|20|45
11|165|5.5
12|180|6
13|195|6.5
14|20|45
15|225|7.5
16|240|8
17|255|8.5
18|270|9
19|285|9.5
```

As you can see, all rows of olddb.People are updated with the values from the first row of newdb.Peeps.

My intention is to update each row in olddb.People with the values from the corresponding rows in newdb.Peeps using the first value (unix) of the row.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing qualifiers `olddb.People` for `unix`. Thus it defaults to the innermost table, so you are doing `WHERE newdb.Peeps.unix = newdb.Peeps.unix` mistakenly.

```
UPDATE olddb.People 
  SET datestamp = 
        (SELECT datestamp FROM newdb.Peeps WHERE olddb.People.unix = newdb.Peeps.unix)
    , value = 
        (SELECT value from newdb.Peeps WHERE olddb.People.unix = newdb.Peeps.unix);
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you for the timely response. Should I change the title to [SOLVED] or anything of the like?

Comment: No leave it as is. As you've accepted an answer it is implicitely solved and displayed as such.